# Finding measure angle

Tags: complex-numbers

If $P$ and $Q$ are points on the unit circle corresponding to complex numbers $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $- \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ resp. What is the measure of angle POQ?
Let $z_{1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \Rightarrow \arg(z_{1})=\frac{\pi}{3}$
and $z_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i \Rightarrow \arg(z_{2})=\frac{2\pi}{3}$
After this what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing an Argand diagram and seeing where these arguments fit in and how they relate to the angle POQ

Answer (score 0):

So, $|OP|=|OQ|=1$ and $|PQ|=1$

So, $$\cos\angle POQ=\frac{OP^2+OQ^2-PQ^2}{2OP\cdot OQ}=\frac12$$